# Why command "run-android" unrecognized?

Tags: react-native, android-studio

```
error Unrecognized command "run-android".
```

even though yesterday I used it I could but now I can't, why? can help me guys?
I use android studio for the emulator

Answer (score 1):

**Possible Reason:**

1. You are not in the correct directory where your App is present.
2. Required Packages not properly installed

**Possible Solutions:**

1. Make sure you are in the same directory where the RN app is present.
2. In case you still facing the same error, then delete the node_modules and run “Yarn install” and then try with your command: react-native run-android